# Intuition why the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ maps lines to circles

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For the function $f(z) := \frac{1}{z}$, is there an intution why it maps complex numbers $z$ to points on a circle?
I did this question where $z$ varied on a line $x=1$, giving $f(z) = w$ with $|w-\frac{1}{2}| = \frac{1}{2}$.
The proof for the above came from just considering the LHS... but surely if I were to just find $w$ algebraically, I would not have realised that $w$ would be a pointon a circle. This is why if a question asked me: "What circle would be the image of $f$ is $z$ varied on $x=30$?" I would have a bit of trouble.

Comment: Try Needham's book: [Google Books link (p. 127)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ogz5FjmiqlQC&lpg=PP1&dq=needham+visual+complex+analysis&pg=PA127&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=re^{i\theta} $ so that $\frac 1z = \frac1r e^{-i\theta}$

The equation of any line parallel to the y-axis is given by $r=x_0 \sec\theta$

So 
$$ \begin{eqnarray*}  
\frac 1z &=& \frac 1{x_0}\cos\theta  e^{-i\theta}
\\   &=& \frac 1{2x_0}( e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}  ) e^{-i\theta}
\\   &=& \frac 1{2x_0}( 1+e^{-2i\theta}  )
\\   &=& \frac 1{2x_0} +\frac 1{2x_0}e^{-2i\theta}  
\end{eqnarray*} $$
Which is clearly a circle (traversed twice) with centre at $\frac 1{2x_0}$ and radius $\frac 1{2x_0}$

This can be generalized to yield circles for any line of the form $y=mx+b$ unless $b=0$ in which case the transformation maps lines onto lines and is equivalent to a reflection in the $x$ axis

Comment: With your specification "(traversed twice)", it seeems that at a point on the line there corresponds two points on the circle.

Comment: Really speaking, the circle can be traversed as many times as the line is traversed. Usually when you provide a parametric equation for a curve, the parameter is enough to take values on as smallest domain as possible needed to describe the curve.

Comment: If, in your parametric equation for the line $r=x_0\sec \theta$, you are assuming that $\theta \in [-\pi, \pi[$, that is the line is traversed only once, then the circle is traversed only once as well. What changes is the sense of rotation of the radius vectors while describing the line and the circle respectively: when one runs clockwisely, the other runs counter-clockwisely.

Comment: Since $\theta$ spans from $-\pi/2$ (when $y\to -\infty$) to $\pi/2$ (when $y\to +\infty$), I would say that it traverses strictly once.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L=\{z \in  \mathbb C: Re(z)=1\}$. If $z \in L$, then $z=1+it$ for some $t \in \mathbb R$. Hence

$f(z)=\frac{1}{1+it}$. Therefore

$|f(z)- \frac{1}{2}|=|\frac{1}{1+it}- \frac{1}{2}|=|\frac{-1-it}{2(1+it)}|=\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: What is the *intuition* behind the result? How would I find the circle if,say, $z$ varied on the line $x=29.5$?

Answer (score 0):

The line $x=30$ in the complex plane (that can be thought of as a circle passing by $30$ and infinity and symmetrical wrt to the real axis) is mapped by $1/z$ into a circle passing by $1/30$ and $0$ with the symmetry preserved.

Answer (score 0):

First of all mirroring doesn't alter this so you can instead consider the map $\overline f(z) = 1/\overline z$ which is inversion in the unit circle. This means that we can interpret it (the image of a point) geometrically (as a point on the line through origin that is at the distance $1/|z|$ from the point).

Now it's a two steps, the first is to establish the image and then to see that it has the required property. I assume that you're familliar with how to construct the image(*) so I skip right to showing how it has the required property.

You have a circle around $M$ that passes through $O$ (the origin in complex plane), you also have a line $L$. We also have that the (extension of) the diameter crosses $L$ under a right angle (that's part of the skipped step), call this point $X$

Now pick a point $A$ on the line and consider the line through $OA$ and let $B$ be the other intersection with the circle. Let $C$ be the midpoint of the line segment $OB$.

[image: B is the image of A under inversion in the unit circle]

Now consider the right triangles $OCM$ (right because it's congruet to $BCM$) and $OXA$, these are similar because they are right and share the angle at $O$. This means that the $OC$ is to $OM$ as $OX$ is to $OA$.

Algebraically this means that

$${OB \over OM} = {2\cdot OC \over OM} = {2\cdot OX\over OA}$$

or

$$OB = 2\cdot OM\cdot OX{1\over OA}$$

But from the skipped step we know that $2\cdot OM\cdot OX$ is the square of the radius of the unit cirle.

(*) You actually have that construct on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Circle_inversion).

Answer (score 0):

Lines and circles are objects given by equations of the form $az\bar z + b z + \bar b \bar z + c = 0$ where $b$ is a complex number and $a$ and $d$ are real numbers, and where $a,b,c$ are not all simultaneously zero.

If $z$ is nonzero, then letting $w= 1/z$, you get $(az\bar z + b z + \bar b \bar z + c)w\bar w = a + b\bar w + \bar b w +dw\bar w$, which is an equation on $w$ of the same form.

So inversion turns lines and circles into lines and circles.

In particular, the lines are the objects you obtain when $a=0$, so they are transformed into the objects you obtain with $d=0$, so lines or circles that go through $0$. So in a sense, the lines are the objects that go through $1/0$, or "the point at infinity".